# Tiempo de ejecucion con bucles for

Tags: algoritmos, bucle-for, complejidad

```
for(int a=1; a<= n, a = a+4){
     for(int b=1; b<=n; b=b + n/4){
          for(int c=1; c<=n; c = c*2){
                print
          }
     }
}
return 1
```

Como influye en la sumatoria la parte 'a+4', 'b + n/4' y 'c*2' para hallar el tiempo de ejecucion

Edito con la sumatoria segun lo que entendi

[image: sumatoria del tiempo de ejecucion]

Comment: Influye en el número de veces que se repite cada bucle. El externo se ejecuta `n/4` veces, dado que `a` se incrementa de 4 en 4. El bucle en `b` se ejecuta 4 veces, puesto que cada vez se incrementa en `n/4` y se detiene al llegar a `n `. El interno se ejecuta `log_2(n)+1` veces, como puedes ver si pones como ejemplo que `n` sea una potencia de 2.